# How does inheritance work for Attributes?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, attributes

What does the `Inherited` bool property on attributes refers to?

Does it mean that if I define my class with an attribute `AbcAtribute` (that has `Inherited = true`), and if I inherit another class from that class, that the derived class will also have that same attribute applied to it?

To clarify this question with a code example, imagine the following:

```c#
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class, Inherited = true)]
public class Random: Attribute
{ /* attribute logic here */ }

[Random]
class Mother 
{ }

class Child : Mother 
{ }
```

Does `Child` also have the `Random` attribute applied to it?

Comment: It was not the case when you asked the question, but today the [official documentation of the `Inherited` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.attributeusageattribute.inherited.aspx) has an elaborate example that shows the difference between `Inherited=true` and `Inherited=false` for both an inherited class and an `override` method.

Answer (score 142, accepted):

When Inherited = true (which is the default) it means that the attribute you are creating can be inherited by sub-classes of the class decorated by the attribute.

So - if you create MyUberAttribute with [AttributeUsage (Inherited = true)]

```
[AttributeUsage (Inherited = True)]
MyUberAttribute : Attribute
{
   string _SpecialName;
   public string SpecialName
   { 
     get { return _SpecialName; }
     set { _SpecialName = value; }
   }
}
```

Then use the Attribute by decorating a super-class...

```
[MyUberAttribute(SpecialName = "Bob")]
class MySuperClass 
{
  public void DoInterestingStuf () { ... }
}
```

If we create an sub-class of MySuperClass it will have this attribute...

```
class MySubClass : MySuperClass
{
   ...
}
```

Then instantiate an instance of MySubClass...

```
MySubClass MySubClassInstance = new MySubClass();
```

Then test to see if it has the attribute...

MySubClassInstance <--- now has the MyUberAttribute with "Bob" as the SpecialName value.

Answer (score 19):

Yes that is precisely what it means. [Attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z0w1kczw(VS.80).aspx)

```
[AttributeUsage(Inherited=true)]
public class FooAttribute : System.Attribute
{
    private string name;

    public FooAttribute(string name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public override string ToString() { return this.name; }
}

[Foo("hello")]
public class BaseClass {}

public class SubClass : BaseClass {}

// outputs "hello"
Console.WriteLine(typeof(SubClass).GetCustomAttributes(true).First());
```

Answer (score 3):

Attribute inheritance is enabled by default.

You can change this behavior by:

```
[AttributeUsage (Inherited = False)]
```