# Cascading the effect of an attribute to overridden properties in child classes

Tags: c#, .net

Is it possible to mark a property in base class with some attribute that remains effective in child classes too?

Question might be very specific to Serialization, but I definitely think there can be other uses as well.

Consider the following code:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace Code.Without.IDE
{
    [Serializable]
    public abstract class C1
    {
        [XmlIgnore]
        public abstract bool IsValid_C1 { get; set;}
    }

    [Serializable]
    public class C2 : C1
    {
        public bool IsValid_C2 { get; set; }

        public override bool IsValid_C1 { get; set;}

        public C2()
        {
            IsValid_C1 = true;
            IsValid_C2 = false;
        }
    }

    public static class AbstractPropertiesAttributeTest
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            C2 c2 = new C2();
            using(MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(C2));
                ser.Serialize(ms, c2);
                string result = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ms.ToArray());
                Console.WriteLine(result);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Above code returns:

```
------ C:\abhi\Code\CSharp\without IDE\AbstractPropertiesAttributeTest.exe 
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<C2 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <IsValid_C2>false</IsValid_C2>
  <IsValid_C1>true</IsValid_C1>
</C2>
------ Process returned 0
```

I thought `IsValid_C1` will be ignored, though it is not so. Is there any way of achieving this other than marking the property as protected?

Edit: A quick code to show that `XmlIgnore` attibute is being inherited.
http://ideone.com/HH41TE

Comment: If `XmlIgnoreAttribute` had been declared with `Inherited = true`, this should work. Alas, it is not, and this is not a way to make it work: http://ideone.com/B0KASa `[AttributeUsageAttribute(AttributeTargets.Property|AttributeTargets.Field|AttributeTargets.Parameter|AttributeTargets.ReturnValue, Inherited = true)]
    public class XmlInheritIgnoreAttribute : System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnoreAttribute
    {
    }`

Comment: @TimS. I tried your code and as you rightly suggested, it did not work in this situation probably because it is not designed for this?

Comment: @abhinav Fair enough, didn't realise.

Comment: Perhaps double? : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1240960/how-does-inheritance-work-for-attributes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe there is a way to inherit the attribute since you override the base class property. You would need to decorate the IsValid_C1 of C2 with XmlIgnore:

```
    [Serializable]
    public class C2 : C1
    {
        public bool IsValid_C2 { get; set; }

        [XmlIgnore]
        public override bool IsValid_C1 { get; set; }

        public C2()
        {
            IsValid_C1 = true;
            IsValid_C2 = false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Unless an attribute has been marked as *un*`Inheritable`, it is automatically cascaded down to derived classes. When I do some reflection on the field IsValid_C1, though a little differently, I can see that it is marked with `XmlIgnoreAttribute`. I believe XmlSerializer does not look this attribute the same way as I did. I do agree that the code above is one of solutions if I need to make it work with `XmlSerializer`.

Comment: I did not know that, and well done for reflecting the code to check, thank you. +1 to you. :)

Answer (score 1):

I will offer a different view of this question. Maybe you just used those properties as an example and want to have severall properties to be cascaded. But i think that this may be a good time to think about the inheritance model proposed.

Basicly you can use regular inheritance or think about some Design Pattern, that can not just solve you issue related to the serialization, but may offer you some more "loose coupling" in you application, making it in a more component model and allowwing each class to deal only with what is concern, this way you can re-use lots of stuff and make your life easier.

Based on that thinking im providing you a sample of the Decorator Design Pattern mixed with the Strategy Design Pattern. If i were developing classes like the ones on your sample, this is how i would do it:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// The interface for validation strategy (since we are using interface, there is no need for another abstract class)
    /// </summary>
    public interface IValidation
    {
        bool IsValid { get; set; }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// The decorator (it dont need to be abstract) that has the serializable properties
    /// </summary>
    [Serializable]
    public class ValidatableDecorator : IValidation
    {
        protected IValidation instance;

        public ValidatableDecorator()
        {
            Init();
        }
        public ValidatableDecorator(IValidation instance)
        {
            Init();
        }

        protected virtual void Init() { }

        public void Set(IValidation instance)
        {
            this.instance = instance;
        }

        [XmlIgnore]
        public bool IsValid
        {
            get
            {
                return instance.IsValid;
            }
            set
            {
                instance.IsValid = value;
            }
        }
    }
```

Then you need to implement some classes that have the logic of the strategy Pattern, like this:

```
    public class BossValidatorImplementation : IValidation
    {

        public bool IsValid
        {
            get
            {
                return false; ;
            }
            set
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException("I dont allow you to tell me this!");
            }
        }
    }

    public class EasyGoingValidator : IValidation
    {
        public bool IsValid { get; set; }
    }
```

Now that we have the logic separated from the class, we can inherit from the decorators, choosing wich strategy they use to the IsValid field, like this:

```
    public class ChildWithBossValidation : ValidatableDecorator
    {
        protected ChildWithBossValidation(IValidation instance)
            : this()
        {
            Init();
        }

        public ChildWithBossValidation()
            : base(new BossValidatorImplementation())
        {
            Init();
        }

        protected override void Init()
        {
            Name = "I'm the boss!";
            Sallary = 10000d;
        }

        public string Name { get; set; }
        public double Sallary { get; set; }

    }

    public class ChildWithEasyGoingValidation : ValidatableDecorator
    {
        public ChildWithEasyGoingValidation()
            : base(new EasyGoingValidator())
        {
        }
        protected ChildWithEasyGoingValidation(IValidation instance)
            : this()
        {
        }

        protected override void Init()
        {
            Name = "Do as you please... :)  ";
        }

        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

This is the code to show that the solution works:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        var boos = new ChildWithBossValidation();
        var coolGuy = new ChildWithEasyGoingValidation();

        using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            var ser = new XmlSerializer(boos.GetType());
            ser.Serialize(ms, boos);
            string result = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ms.ToArray());
            Console.WriteLine("With override");
            Console.WriteLine(result);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("-------------");

        using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            var ser = new XmlSerializer(coolGuy.GetType());
            ser.Serialize(ms, coolGuy);
            string result = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ms.ToArray());
            Console.WriteLine("With override");
            Console.WriteLine(result);
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

The result is:

```
{<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ChildWithBossValidation xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Name>I'm the boss!</Name>
  <Sallary>10000</Sallary>
</ChildWithBossValidation>-------------------<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ChildWithEasyGoingValidation xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Name>Do as you please... :)  </Name>
</ChildWithEasyGoingValidation>}
```

So, maybe this does not answer how to cascade the Attribute in this case (because you can easily do it by creating your own attribute(marking to allow inheritance) and then implementing some code to SerializeXML). This is just another option that can improve overall architecture of solutions using Design Pattern. But this solve this particular issue also :)

Answer (score 1):

A needed behaviour can be achieved using classes XmlAttributeOverrides and XmlAttributes. I've written helper method for XmlSerializer creation:

```
    public static XmlSerializer GetXmlSerializerWithXmlIgnoreFields(Type t)
    {
        XmlAttributeOverrides xmlOverrides = new XmlAttributeOverrides();

        foreach (var prop in t.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public|BindingFlags.Instance))
        {
            Attribute xmlIgnoreAttribute = Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(prop, typeof(XmlIgnoreAttribute));
            if (xmlIgnoreAttribute == null) 
                continue;

            XmlAttributes xmlAttributes = new XmlAttributes();
            xmlAttributes.XmlIgnore = true;
            xmlOverrides.Add(t, prop.Name, xmlAttributes);
        }

        return new XmlSerializer(t, xmlOverrides);
    }
```

The Main method became:

```
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        C2 c2 = new C2();
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            XmlSerializer ser = GetXmlSerializerWithXmlIgnoreFields(typeof(C2));
            ser.Serialize(ms, c2);
            string result = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ms.ToArray());
            Console.WriteLine(result);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears this feature is broken in C#.

You could write an attribute which through reflection will bring down the attributes for you.  Pretty straight forward if you understand reflection.