# Routes mapping in MVC 5

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, routes, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm trying to understand how the route config works in the MVC 5.

I have the following structure for my application:

**BaseCRUDController**

```
public class BaseCRUDController<TEntity, TEntityViewModel> : Controller 
    where TEntity : class
    where TEntityViewModel : class
{
    private readonly IBaseService<TEntity> baseService;

    public BaseCRUDController(IBaseService<TEntity> service)
    {
        this.baseService = service;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public virtual ActionResult Index()
    {
        IList<TEntityViewModel> entities = baseService.FindFirst(10).To<IList<TEntityViewModel>>();
        return View(entities);
    }
```

}

**CountriesController**

```
[RouteArea("management")]
[RoutePrefix("countries")]
public class CountriesController : BaseCRUDController<Country, CountryViewModel>
{
    private readonly ICountryService service;

    public CountriesController(ICountryService service) 
        : base(service)
    {
        this.service = service;
    }
}
```

What I'm trying to do is simple: http://myapplication.com/management/countries.
I have many others controllers that the superclass is the base controller. I'm doing this way to avoid code repetition, since that the controllers have similar structure.

The problems are:

- I can't reach the url that I want (/management/countries)
- I don't know how to configure my Home Controller, because I want that it could be reached by http://myapplication.com

How could I fix these problems?

My route config is like that:

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Please define exactly what errors you're getting (i.e. 404, or view not found etc), and also provide your route config. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

After a little playing around I managed to get it to work.

The problem is when you are using attribute routing there are no default route parameters assigned.

For example in your `Default` route the defaults are `controller = "Home", action = "Index"`. So if you were to call http://myapplication.com/ the routing engine will automatically default to `/Home/Index/` and so on.

However the attribute route has no way of knowing you want to default to the `Index` action (or any other action for that matter).

To solve the issue add the `Route` attribute to the `CountriesController` like this:

```
[RouteArea("management")]
[RoutePrefix("countries")]
[Route("{action=Index}")] // this defines the default action as Index
public class CountriesController : BaseCRUDController<Country, CountryViewModel>
{
    private readonly ICountryService service;

    public CountriesController(ICountryService service) 
        : base(service)
    {
        this.service = service;
    }
}
```

Also for future reference [Phil Haack's Route Debugger](https://www.nuget.org/packages/routedebugger/) is extremely helpful for figuring out routing issues.

Comment: Do you know why it doesn't work when I put the route attribute in the base class?

Comment: Most likely because the attribute is not inheritable, take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1240960/how-does-inheritance-work-for-attributes

Answer (score 0):

Have you defined Area (management) for your controllers?
if you try without Area, is that getting redirect properly?