# Cannot get attributes of implementing class

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have a behavior that takes the display name attribute and sets the column header of a data grid when it is auto generated. I works fine when the grid is bound to a collection of one specific type. If I have a collection of some base type it will not work although if I don't use my behavior it will have no problem auto generating columns of the derived class from the base class.

When the collection type is of the base class the only attributes that are found are from the base class, I want to be able to show the attributes from the implementing collection.

Ideas?

The problem is:
`DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs.PropertyDescriptor` is giving property information for the declared value type of the collection, not the actual item type.

behavior code:

```
        #region Setup

    /// <summary>
    /// Called when [attached].
    /// </summary>
    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        base.OnAttached();
        AssociatedObject.AutoGeneratingColumn += HandleAutoGeneratingColumns;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Called when [detaching].
    /// </summary>
    protected override void OnDetaching()
    {
        base.OnDetaching();
        AssociatedObject.AutoGeneratingColumn -= HandleAutoGeneratingColumns;
    }

    #endregion

    #region Helpers

    /// <summary>
    /// Handles the automatic generating columns.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender">The sender.</param>
    /// <param name="dataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs">The <see cref="DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs"/> instance containing the event data.</param>
    private void HandleAutoGeneratingColumns(object sender, DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs dataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs)
    {
        if (AssociatedObject != null)
        {
            var displayName = GetPropertyDisplayName(dataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs.PropertyDescriptor);

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(displayName))
            {
                dataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs.Column.Header = displayName;
                dataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs.Column.Width = new DataGridLength(1, DataGridLengthUnitType.Star);
            }
            else
            {
                dataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs.Column.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            }
        }
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the display name of the property.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="descriptor">The descriptor.</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    [CanBeNull]
    private static string GetPropertyDisplayName(object descriptor)
    {
        string returnValue = null;

        var propertyDescriptor = descriptor as PropertyDescriptor;
        if (propertyDescriptor != null)
        {
            var displayName = propertyDescriptor.Attributes[typeof(DisplayNameAttribute)] as DisplayNameAttribute;
            if (displayName != null && !Equals(displayName, DisplayNameAttribute.Default))
            {
                returnValue = displayName.DisplayName;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            var propertyInfo = descriptor as PropertyInfo;
            if (propertyInfo != null)
            {
                var attributes = propertyInfo.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DisplayNameAttribute), true);
                foreach (var attribute in attributes)
                {
                    var displayName = attribute as DisplayNameAttribute;
                    if (displayName != null && !Equals(displayName, DisplayNameAttribute.Default))
                    {
                        returnValue = displayName.DisplayName;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return returnValue;
    }
```

Sample from one binding property

```
public class DefaultMatchedItems : ILookupItem
{
    #region Properties

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the first column value.
    /// </summary>
    [DisplayName("Long Name")]
    [CanBeNull]
    public string FirstColumnValue { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the second column value.
    /// </summary>
    [DisplayName("Short Name")]
    [CanBeNull]
    public string SecondColumnValue { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the third column value.
    /// </summary>
    [DisplayName("Abbreviation")]
    [CanBeNull]
    public string ThirdColumnValue { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the identifier.
    /// </summary>
    [Browsable(false)]
    [NotNull]
    public string Identifier { get; set; }


    public interface ILookupItem
{

    /// <summary>
    /// Determines whether [contains] [the specified value].
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="value">The value.</param>
    /// <param name="ignoreCase">if set to <c>true</c> [ignore case].</param>
    /// <returns>
    ///   <c>true</c> if [contains] [the specified value]; otherwise, <c>false</c>.
    /// </returns>
    bool Contains(string value, bool ignoreCase = true);

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the display value.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="identifier">The identifier.</param>
    /// <returns>The first non blank section of the matching value</returns>
    string GetDisplayValue(string identifier);

}
```

Comment: Where is base class? For attributes you have to use [`[AttributeUsage(Inherited=true)]`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1240975/1997232) to have them in inherited class.

Comment: *“When the collection type is of the base class the only attributes that are found are from the base class, I want to be able to show the attributes from the implementing collection.”* — it's not clear to which part of your code this problem statement relates. Please improve your question.

Comment: At a guess,  `DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs.PropertyDescriptor` is giving you property information for the declared value type of the collection, not the actual item type. I would put in a breakpoint and check that. It makes sense: If there are disparate actual subclass objects in the collection, which should it use for column information? You may want to ignore what it's giving you there, and scan through the collection yourself. 'Course, if it's empty, you're stuck with whatever `T` is for the collection.

Answer (score 2):

#### How columns get populated

When a `DataGrid` auto-populates columns, it uses `IItemProperties` to interrogate its `Items` collection view about what properties are available.  What you are seeing is a consequence of *how* those properties are resolved.  The relevant logic is provided by the `CollectionView` class, and the steps are as follows:

1. If the collection implements `ITypedList`, it will use `ITypedList.GetItemProperties()`.
2. If the collection implements `IEnumerable<T>` for any `T` **other than** `System.Object`, it will use `TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(typeof(T))`.
3. If there are items in the collection, it grabs a 'representative item' from the beginning of the collection and:

   1. If the representative item implements `ICustomTypeProvider`, it uses `ICustomTypeProvider.GetCustomType().GetProperties()`.
   2. It falls back to `TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(representativeItem)`.

If the process fails on step (3) because no items are available for inspection, the `DataGrid` will defer column generation until items are added, at which point it will try again.

#### How this affects you

If your `ItemsSource` is an `IEnumerable<ILookupItem>`, then the columns will be generated by looking only at `ILookupItem`.

You can work around this by forcing the `CollectionView` to use a different strategy when resolving item properties.  For example, you could bind to an `IEnumerable<DefaultMatchedItems>` or an `IEnumerable<object>`; have your collection implement `ITypedList`; or have `ILookupItem` implement `ICustomTypeProvider`.

Interestingly, while `DataGrid` relies on `IItemProperties` to resolve item properties, it will **only** use this interface to iterrogate its `Items` collection view.  It will **not** attempt to probe its `ItemsSource` directly, even if it implements `IItemProperties`.  I have always found that odd.

Answer (score 0):

`DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs.PropertyDescriptor` is giving you property information for the declared item type of the collection bound to `AssociatedObject.ItemsSource`.

I can recreate this with the following classes, if I bind a collection of type `ObservableCollection<ItemBase>` (or `List<ItemBase>`, of course), and populate it with instances of `ItemSub`.

```
public class ItemBase
{
    [DisplayName("Base Foo")]
    public virtual String Foo { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("All Bar")]
    public virtual String Bar { get; set; }
}

public class ItemSub : Item
{
    [DisplayName("Sub Foo")]
    public override String Foo { get; set; }
}
```

For `Foo`, `e.PropertyDescriptor.DisplayName` is "Base Foo".

If I change the collection type to `ObservableCollection<Object>` (only for testing purposes -- collections of `object` generally aren't good practice), `e.PropertyDescriptor.DisplayName` is "Sub Foo". If I then change the type of the *first* item in the collection to `ItemBase`, I get "Base Foo".

So your best move may be to get the property name from the event args, but go to `AssociatedObject.Items` to get the runtime type of an actual item in the collection, and use the attributes from that type.