# Why custom type attributes not inherited in generics?

Tags: c#, .net, generics

I have attribute

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class)]
public class CacheAttribute : Attribute
{        
}
```

and generic class

```
[Cache]    
public class BaseClass<T>
{        
}
```

and another class

```
public class ImplClass : BaseClass<Type>
{        
}
```

When i try to get custom attributes from

```
BaseClass<Type>
```

I get my attribute, but not from

```
ImplClass
```

My code to get Custom attributes is

```
typeof(ImplClass).CustomAttributes -> 0
typeof(BaseClass<Type>).CustomAttributes -> 1
```

How can i inherite attribute to my implementation?

> **NOTE:** There is a similar question [How does inheritance work for Attributes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1240960/how-does-inheritance-work-for-attributes) that is **not helpful**. Unlike that issue, this one is about attribute inheritance in combination with generics.

Comment: @Sinatr The mentioned already answered quetion is not the same.

Comment: DavidG The mentioned already answered question is not the same. Here is generic issue

Comment: I suggest adding the Reflection code to your question that you are using to read the attribute. If this is indeed a new question related specifically to generics, it can be reopened.

Comment: @NightOwl888 it's trivial like typeof(ImplClass).CustomAttributes

Comment: Even trivial code can potentially have bugs in it. Besides, you need to provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) as proof this is not a duplicate of the other question, so it can be reopened. How are we supposed to be able to run this to confirm what you are saying is true and provide a solution if we don't have the same code as you? There is currently nothing runnable in your question.

Comment: @NightOwl888 ok, understood

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does inheritance work for Attributes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1240960/how-does-inheritance-work-for-attributes)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your attribute *is* inherited by your child class. The problem you encounter is not specific to generics. It can easily be reproduced with non-generic types:

```
using System.Linq;

[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class)]
public class FooAttribute : Attribute
{
    private readonly string name;

    public FooAttribute(string name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }
}

[Foo("bar")]
public class Base { }
public class Child : Base { }

Console.WriteLine(typeof(Base).CustomAttributes.Count());  // Prints 1.
Console.WriteLine(typeof(Child).CustomAttributes.Count()); // Prints 0.
```

From the documentation of [`MemberInfo.CustomAttributes`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.memberinfo.customattributes(v=vs.110).aspx):

> Gets a collection that contains this member's custom attributes.

So this property just gets the attributes applied to the type itself, not inherited ones (the implementation in `MemberInfo` calls `GetCustomAttributesData` which in turn just throws an `NotImplementedException` and i could not find an override in `Type` so i assume this to be right).

However you can use one of the [MemberInfo.GetCustomAttributes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getcustomattributes(v=vs.110).aspx) overloads  or one of [these](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.customattributeextensions_methods(v=vs.110).aspx) extension methods to get inherited attributes

```
typeof(ImplClass).GetCustomAttributes(typeof(CacheAttribute), inherit: true)
```