# C# validation attributes for derived class

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, validation, attributes

I have a base class with some properties:

```
public class A
{
   [Display(Name = "Some Property")]
   public virtual int SomeProperty {get;set;}
}
```

and its derived class:

```
public class B:A
{
   [Required]
   public override int SomeProperty {get;set;}
}
```

But in fact, when I extract metadata for class B to ModelMetadata, IsRequired property is set to false. Is there a way to apply Required attribute, so it was reflected in ModelMetadata?

Comment: What validation framework are you using?

Comment: Review this SO [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1240960/how-does-inheritance-work-for-attributes)

Comment: @ZakkDiaz standart ASP.NET MVC validation

Answer (score 0):

Please try the example below:

```
public class A
{
    [Display(Name = "Some Property")]
    public virtual int SomeProperty { get; set; }
}
public class B : A
{
    [MyRequired]
    public override int SomeProperty { get; set; }
}

[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property, Inherited = true)]

public class MyRequiredAttribute : RequiredAttribute
{

}
```

finally:

[image: test of code]

Comment: And why would subclassing `RequiredAttribute` work if using `RequiredAttribute` doesn't?

Comment: Because you have to set inherited property true