# C# Reflection - GetCustomAttributes for Type gets attribute from parent class

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, system.reflection

Let's say I have two classes, the base class has a custom attribute:

```
[MyAttribute]
public class BaseModel
{
    public string Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class InheritedModel : BaseModel
{
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }

    public int Amount { get; set; }
}
```

When I'm working with inherited class, like

```
// member.DeclaringType is InheritedModel 

if (member.DeclaringType.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(MyAttribute)).Any())
{
   // returns true
}
```

I expect this should be `false` because `InheritedModel` has not `MyAttribute` attribute directly.

It it correct behaviour? How can I divide parents and inheritors in condition above?

Comment: You can change this behaviour by setting `Inherited = false` in AttributeUsage

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1240960/how-does-inheritance-work-for-attributes

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does inheritance work for Attributes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1240960/how-does-inheritance-work-for-attributes)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[GetCustromAttributes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.attribute.getcustomattributes?view=netframework-4.8#System_Attribute_GetCustomAttributes_System_Reflection_ParameterInfo_System_Type_System_Boolean_) has an overload which lets you specify if you want to search ancestor classes as well.

It seems to default to `true` (though it doesn't say in the docs) so try passing `false`

```
member.DeclaringType.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(MyAttribute), false).Any()
```