# How to disable c# Attribute that inherits from parent class?

Tags: c#, class, inheritance, attributes

Maybe it's quite easy but I cannot find a way to do this

```
[ExecuteAlways] // some third party attribute
public class A  // and this class is also third party
{

}

// I don't want the ExecuteAlwasy attribute in B
// [!ExecuteAlways] < this is what I want
public class B : A
{

}
```

So how can I remove the attribute for only class B?
Note that class A is not editable.

Comment: Can you change the attribute's code? The inheritance properties are defined by the attribute itself.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot change the attribute's code either.

Comment: Can you post the code for Attribute?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1241121/477878

Comment: There is no easy way to do this if the attribute is set to inherit, you will need to rethink your design

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both the codes of the parent class `A` and attribute `[ExecuteAlways]` are not editable. I don't believe there is a way to disable this attribute in B.