# Inherit attribute during serialization when implementing abstract base field

Tags: c#, .net, system.text.json

I have an abstract class `Base` that wants every derived class to implement a property `SortValue`. This property should have an attribute applied for all derived instances, in this case `JsonIgnore`.

What's happening appears to be that the attribute is not respected for `Derived`. At least, the property is not ignored when serialized by System.Text.Json.

How can I achieve attribute inheritance while ensuring every subclass implements `SortValue`?

```
public abstract class Base
{
    [JsonIgnore]
    public abstract IComparable SortValue { get; }
}

public class Derived : Base
{
    public int VoteCount { get; set; }

    // Desire: inherited JsonIgnore attribute
    public override IComparable SortValue => VoteCount;
}
```

Comment: Did you set `[AttributeUsage (Inherited = true)]`? See [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1240960/how-does-inheritance-work-for-attributes)

Comment: "the attribute is lost when the property is declared as override" - what does it mean?

Comment: Clarified the question -- I mean it is not respected for Derived instances. I assume that means it isn't being inherited, hence "lost"

Comment: so you want `VoteCount` hidden?

Comment: @DanielA.White - no, SortValue should be ignored when serialized. VoteCount is the serialized property here.

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/30619

Comment: I don't understand how that link applies.

Comment: Seems to be reproducible, `JsonSerializer.Serialize(derived, typeof(Derived))` includes `"SortValue":{}` but `JsonSerializer.Serialize(derived, typeof(Base));` does not, see https://dotnetfiddle.net/klwMQr.  Feels like a bug in `JsonSerializer`.

Comment: Thanks. I guess my question should have included: is it expected that JsonIgnore is inherited for Derived?

Answer (score 1):

**Update: this is intended behavior of `System.Text.Json`:**

In [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63621028/inherit-attribute-during-serialization-when-implementing-abstract-base-field#comment112511668_63624207) [Noah Stahl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2411713/noah-stahl) links to [this issue](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/39790#issuecomment-663055706)

> **[System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize ignores JsonPropertyName on abstract properties #3979](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/39790)**
>
> This is known/by design. Properties cannot inherit System.Text.Json attributes. The attributes need to be placed on each (de)serializable override.

**As a workaround**, you could make make `SortValue` be a public, non-virtual surrogate that calls some protected abstract property like so:

```
public abstract class Base
{
    protected abstract IComparable ProtectedSortValue { get; }
    
    [JsonIgnore]
    public IComparable SortValue => ProtectedSortValue;
}

public class Derived : Base
{
    public int VoteCount { get; set; }

    protected override IComparable ProtectedSortValue => VoteCount;
}
```

With this change, `SortValue` will not be serialized in derived classes while `ProtectedSortValue` will not be serialized at all, since only public properties are serialized.  Demo fiddle #3 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/y2d2KL).

(Adding `[JsonIgnore]` to the overridden property also prevents its serialization, however it would be necessary to do this in every derived class, which it appears you do not want to do.)

**Original answer: This may be a limitation of `System.Text.Json`.** I was able to reproduce your problem using the following code:

```
var derived = new Derived { VoteCount = 101 };

var json1 = JsonSerializer.Serialize(derived, typeof(Derived));
Console.WriteLine(json1); // {"VoteCount":101,"SortValue":{}}

var json2 = JsonSerializer.Serialize(derived, typeof(Base));
Console.WriteLine(json2); //{}
```

When an instance of `Derived` is serialized as type `Derived`, the `SortValue` property is included; but when serialized as type `Base` it is not.  Demo fiddle #1 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/klwMQr).

But is this behavior intended?  Neither the [overview docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-how-to#exclude-individual-properties) nor the [`JsonIgnoreAttribute` docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.jsonignoreattribute?view=netcore-3.1) discuss whether `[JsonIgnore]` is inherited, however the [.Net 3.1 source code for `JsonIgnoreAttribute`](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/v3.1.7/src/System.Text.Json/src/System/Text/Json/Serialization/JsonIgnoreAttribute.cs) as well as the [current source](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/master/src/libraries/System.Text.Json/src/System/Text/Json/Serialization/Attributes/JsonIgnoreAttribute.cs) show `[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property, AllowMultiple = false)]`:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property, AllowMultiple = false)]
public sealed class JsonIgnoreAttribute : JsonAttribute
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of <see cref="JsonIgnoreAttribute"/>.
    /// </summary>
    public JsonIgnoreAttribute() { }
}
```

Notice that `AttributeUsageAttribute.Inherited` is not set.  Since the default value for `Inherited` is [documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.attributeusageattribute.inherited?view=netcore-3.1) as follows:

> `true` if the attribute can be inherited by derived classes and overriding members; otherwise, `false`. **The default is `true`**.

It seems that `[JsonIgnore]` should have been inherited by the overridden property.  It is certainly inconsistent with both Json.NET and `DataContractJsonSerializer`, which respectively honor inheritance for `Newtonsoft.Json.JsonIgnoreAttribute` and `IgnoreDataMemberAttribute` as shown in demo fiddle #2 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/rGuXkL).  You might want to [open an issue](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues?q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+label%3Aarea-System.Text.Json) about this; at the minimum the documentation should be clarified.

Comment: Great info, thanks! To confirm, is it expected that an inheritable attribute should work for a derived override of abstract property? (in C# generally)

Comment: @NoahStahl -  In general that should be controlled by [`AttributeUsageAttribute.Inherited`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.attributeusageattribute.inherited?view=netcore-3.1) applied to the attribute, which has a default value of `true`.  The question [linked to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1240960/how-does-inheritance-work-for-attributes) in comments discusses this.

Comment: @NoahStahl - That being said, it is *possible* using reflection to get only the directly applied attributes, so if one is writing code that uses reflection extensively (which a serializer certainly does) then one can avoid that standard if one wants.

Comment: I just found this in the repo. Looks like this is intended by .NET team? https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/39790#issuecomment-663055706

Comment: And there's a section further down in the docs page that discusses how things work in derived types. Seems like this is the reason for the behavior. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-how-to#serialize-properties-of-derived-classes